# Docker shouldn't write new files to original directories

Tags: linux, bash, docker, docker-compose

I have a project with the directory structure as follows:

```
docker-compose.yml
project1/
--Dockerfile
--docker-compose-entry.sh
project2/
--Dockerfile
--docker-compose-entry.sh
project3/
--Dockerfile
--docker-compose-entry.sh
```

My `docker-compose-entry.sh` files create and write some files within the container as they spin up. But this doing another weird thing. When they write files within their containers, they also write files to the original directories in my local.

I want the files to be written within the containers when they fire up and stay within the container without touching my actual directories. The generated files should be destroyed as the container gets destroyed.

Does anyone has suggestion how to do this? Any idea will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE** Following is the content of my files as requested in comments:

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '2'

services:
  project1:
    restart: always
    build: ./project1
    image: project1
    command: gunicorn project1.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./project1:/project1
      - ./common:/project1/common
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  project2:
    restart: always
    build: ./project2
    image: project2
    command: gunicorn project2.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./project2:/project2
      - ./common:/project2/common
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  project3:
    restart: always
    build: ./project3
    image: project3
    command: gunicorn project3.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./project3:/project3
      - ./common:/project3/common
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: sacrina
volumes:
  data:
```

Here is a example of my Dockerfile from project1.

```
#Dockerfile

FROM wildfish/django:node-latest

RUN mkdir /project1
WORKDIR /project1
ADD . /project1

ADD requirements.txt /project1/
ADD ./common/.bowerrc /project1/
ADD ./common/bower.json /project1/
ADD ./common/package.json /project1/
ADD ./common/gulpfile.js /project1/
ADD ./config/ /project1/

RUN pip install -r /project1/requirements.txt
RUN npm install --global bower gulp-cli

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entry-point.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entry-point.sh"]
```

Here is an example of my docker-entry-point.sh

```
# docker-entry-point.sh

#!/bin/sh

npm install
bower install
gulp

python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
gunicorn project1.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: Your desired behaviour is how docker works, unless you're writing to a directory that is mounted from the host.

Comment: To expand on @Paulpro, if you include the content of your shell scripts we can probably tell you why you're getting local copies ( mounts?)

Comment: ...and (especially) the contents of the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have updated my question with my file contents.

Comment: @sshussain270 remove the volume mounts and the writes will happen inside the container instead of on your host.

Comment: Thank you @BMitch this worked! if you can submit this as answer, I can mark it as correct. While we are on the subject, all containers for project1,2,3, load on different ip addresses for some reason. Do you know if I can load them up on the same ip address?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing `volumes`. What are you doing is

First you copy all contents from subfolders into containers on build stage in youe `Dockerfile`: `ADD . /project1`. 
After doing that, you already have `/project1` with all contents in your container and can use it.

But then, when you launch your containers with `docker-compose`, you create additional `binding` with

```
volumes:
  - ./project2:/project2
```

and thus you

1) overwrite your content in container with host's folder

2) enable container to modify the host's folder, because the binding is writable (to create readonly, you specify `- ./project2:/project2:ro`

What you have to do is simply remove this volume declaration from `docker-compose` and enjoy.

By the way, if all your communications run between containers in one `docker-compose` and you leave `network` mode unspecified (defaults to `bridge`), you dont need to explicitly expose ports, like you do in

```
expose:
  - "8000"
```